# Rails, ActiveModel Model Associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the follow two models:

```
User
Mentions (user_id, mentioned_by)
```

@mention.user gives me the creator, but I need the user who was mention. I would like to do: @mention.mentioner which gets the user_id with mentioned_by

How do I set that relationship in the models? I tried:

```
User.rb:
  has_many :mentions


Mention.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :user, :as => "mentioner", :foreign_key => "mentioned_by"
```

But that errors. Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `mention.rb`, try this:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :mentioner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "mentioned_by"
```